# Build Fails With Spread Operator on Travis CI Only

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, create-react-app

my build, `npm run build`, for my website works locally, but on Travis CI it fails with the following error:

```
> node scripts/build.js
/home/travis/build/PatrickDuncan/patrickduncan.github.io/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/deep-equal.js:39
    options = { prototype: true, ...options };
                                 ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/PatrickDuncan/patrickduncan.github.io/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
```

I have `babel-preset-stage-3` in my package.json, so I don't know what the issue is. I have no extraneous packages installed either.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "personal_website",
  "homepage": "http://patrickduncan.co",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "1.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.13.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.5.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.7.1",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.6.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-scrollchor": "^6.0.0",
    "resolve": "1.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "semver": "6.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "victory": "^32.2.3",
    "webpack": "4.29.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "beforeDeploy": "node scripts/beforeDeploy.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/*.js* src/*/*.js* src/*/*/*.js*"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./scripts/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }
}
```

node v10.15.1

npm v6.4.1

Comment: so it works in your local? i.e. if you run `node scripts/build.js` in your local ?

Comment: @Rikin Yes, it works perfectly fine locally.

Comment: try deleting node_module directory in your local and then run `node scripts/build.js` if you have not done that already to rule out issue.

Comment: @Rikin it throws an error as expected

Comment: Not clear what you meant, it throws error same as TravisCI in your local?

Comment: It throws `Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/chalk'` since there are no packages installed

Comment: Can you share your package json

Comment: @Rikin I edited my original post

Comment: what node version used at server?

Comment: @skyboyer Hi, I updated my post again

Comment: Why not use preset-env instead of the proposal plugin?

Comment: Is this your travis.yml? https://github.com/PatrickDuncan/patrickduncan.github.io/blob/development/.travis.yml If so your Node version is very old and probably should be updated to use `lts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
node_js:
 - "lts/*"
```

Change your node version in your `.travis.yml` to use lts and that should resolve it.